# How to write a jQuery/JS function so that it returns a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return-value

How do I write a jQuery function so that it returns a value that I can access outside the function? I did something like this but when I tried to access it outside the function, it says "undefined":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function add(y, z) {
        $('p').click(function() {
            x = y + z;
            console.log(x); // shows 3
            return x;
        });     
    }

    var sum = add(1, 2);

    console.log(sum); // shows "undefined"
});
```

Comment: why do you have the click event within the function? Also, you do not necessarily need to declare functions within the `ready()` method.

Comment: I think I'll create another question for that now that I know that the click event is the problem. For now this question is resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work. Not sure why you added the `click` event there

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function add(y, z) {
        x = y + z;
        console.log(x); // shows 3
        return x;
    }
    var sum = add(1, 2);

    console.log(sum); 
});
```

Comment: I understand everything except console.log() what is that for?

Comment: console.log() is for debugging using Firefox's Firebug.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer - you can't.

The method *registered* by `.click()` is called asynchronously as part of the Javascript event loop.

Your `add` function has *no* return value at all.

If instead what you're trying to do is to create a jQuery style *utility* function, rather than a method that acts on *elements*, you would do this:

```
(function($) {
     $.add = function(y, z) {
         return y + z;
     }
})(jQuery);
```

usage:

```
var x = $.add(1, 2);
```

Comment: @RAJ... I can assure you the code above does work.  If it's not doing what you expect then you're calling it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
function add(y, z) {
   $('p').click(function() {
        x = y + z;
        console.log(x); // shows 3
        return x;
    });   
    return y + z;
}
```

Comment: you're doing the same thing twice

Comment: I think that's only way to make this `var sum = add(1, 2);` work right?

Comment: No, he's doing two very different things.  He leaves in the setup for the click event, and he adds and returns the numbers y and z.

Comment: But he is expecting this `console.log(sum);` to print the sum?

Answer (score 0):

The function, in that case, is an anonymous callback function that is called when the click event occurs.  The way you set it up, what function `add(x, y)` does is create a new handler for click events on

tags.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why click event is added to the function. It should be handled separately. The code should look like this which makes sense according to me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function add(y, z) {
    var x = y + z; // good to make it local scope
    console.log(x); // shows 3
    return x;
}
var sum = add(1, 2);
document.write(sum); // shows "undefined"
});
```